# 32 inch or 27 inch 4k monitor for programming for my 15” macbook pro 2017

Tags: macos, display

I want to buy an external monitor primarily for programming, and occasionally for watching movies and TV series. I have the LG 32UN650 model in mind. However, I've come across different articles mentioning that macOS doesn't scale well for 4K monitors, resulting in blurry text. Since I'll be primarily working with code editors, text clarity is of utmost importance to me. A larger monitor would be a big plus in terms of productivity and multitasking. Unfortunately, I don't have the budget for a 5K monitor.

I've also learned that non-integer scaling requires additional RAM and GPU resources. Will my 2017 15" intel 16GB MacBook Pro with dedicated Radeon Pro 555 GPU be able to handle the load?

Comment: [This technical specs page](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP756?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) by Apple on your MBP says it can support up to two 5K displays simultaneously in addition to the in-built display or four 4K displays. What makes you think that Apple might be misleading the consumers by these statements?

Comment: I am not saying that MBP wont support 4k external monitor. On scaling 4k monitor to 2k resolution can lead to blurry text. Please read the question again.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason why macOS can't scale a 4K display to a 2x scaled 1920 x 1080.

The issue isn't the size, but the pixel density. MacOS is designed to work with hi-density displays, such as the Retina screen of the MacBook Pro.

Low-density displays can have blurry text, due to the lack of sub-pixel rendering.

If you get a 4K display, you want one with a smaller physical size, such as 27", giving 163 pixels per inch, instead of 138ppi for a 32". Still less than the 218 - 256ppi of Apple displays, of course.

Comment: I don't want to scale to 1080 as UI will be very big nor I will scale it on 4k as UI will be too small. I want to use 4k monitor with 2k scaling, which could lead to fuzzy text.

Comment: @TonyStark a 4K monitor at 2x scaling gives a scaled resolution of 1920 x 1080.  (3840 / 2 = 1920.) Fuzzy text is mostly dependent on pixel density, as said.